# Is the ELF .notes section really needed?

Tags: elf, strip, binutils, sections

On Linux, I'm trying to strip a statically linked ELF file to the bare essentials.  When I run:

```
strip --strip-unneeded foo
```

or

```
strip --strip-all foo
```

The resulting file still has a fat .notes section that appears to be full of funky strings.

Is the .notes section really needed or can I safely force it out with --remove-section?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From experience and from looking at the man page for `strip`, it looks like `strip` isn't *supposed* to get rid of any and all sections and strings that aren't needed; just *symbols*. Quoth the man page:

> ```
>    GNU strip discards all symbols from object files objfile.
> ```

That being said, from experience, `strip`, even without `--strip-all`, removes sections unneeded for loading, such as `.symtab` and `.strtab`, and you can, as you note, remove sections you want it with `--remove-section`.

As an example of a `.notes` section, I took `/bin/ls` from my Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit box:

```
$ readelf -Wn /bin/ls

Notes at offset 0x00000254 with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.15

Notes at offset 0x00000274 with length 0x00000024:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 3e6f3159144281f709c3c5ffd41e376f53b47952
```

That encompasses the `.note.ABI-tag` section and the `.note.gnu.build-id` section. It looks like they contain data that isn't necessary to load the program, but also isn't standard, and isn't known by `strip` to not be necessary for the proper running of the program, since an ELF can have any number of additional "unknown" sections that aren't safe to remove. So rather using a virtual whitelist (which would fail miserably), it uses a blacklist of sections that it knows it can get rid of, and does so.

Short version: these sections don't seem to be standard and could be used for various things, so `strip` can't know it's safe to remove them. But based on the info inside the one I took above, if it's your own program, it's almost certainly safe to remove it.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: Some references to what .note.gnu.build-id is: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId and what people do about it: it https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/12/15/162

Comment: strip --remove-section=.note.gnu.build-id <binary>