# What is NT_GNU_BUILD_ID used for?

Tags: linux, go, gnu

I was reading the help guide for [golang ld](https://golang.org/cmd/ld/) and one of the options is

```
-B value
    Add a NT_GNU_BUILD_ID note when using ELF.  The value
    should start with 0x and be an even number of hex digits.
```

Does anyone knows why one would use that flag ?

searching for `NT_GNU_BUILD_ID` does not provide any insightful answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes from the [massive conversion from C to Go of `cmd/new5l`](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1f9dbb60ef5cf8b0027c1149fdb1d6f08c41cfed) (Feb. 2015), translated from [`src/cmd/ld/pobj.c`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/30e36983f381e366e470d6c92e62e5804cbb9712/src/cmd/ld/pobj.c#L83)

That information was introduced in [commit 7d507dc6e](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/7d507dc6e608e800bc26a5850259bbdb05abdf65) (Dec. 2013, for Go 1.3), a preparation for the new linker structure

`NT_GNU_BUILD_ID` is [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416478/6309) as a unique build ID bitstring.
You see it employed for instance in [Fedora release build](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/FeatureBuildId)

> To embed an ID into both the stripped object and its `.debug` file, I've chosen to use an ELF note section.
>   `strip` et al can keep the section intact in both files when its type is `SHT_NOTE`.
>
> The new section is canonically called `.note.gnu.build-id`, but the name is not normative, and the section can be merged with other `SHT_NOTE` sections.
>   The ELF note headers give name "`GNU`" and type 3 (`NT_GNU_BUILD_ID`) for a build ID note, of which there can be only one in a linked object (or an `ET_REL` file of the `.ko` style).

You can see it [introduced in this patch in 2007](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2007-07/msg00012.html):

> This patch adds a new option to `ld` for ELF targets, `--build-id`.
>   It generates a synthetic ELF note section containing "`unique build ID`" bits
>   chosen by `ld`.
>
> This is done as an `ld` option to be efficient and foolproof to enable for
>   every compilation (vs some script adding a generated object into the link).
>   It's done the way it is so it can use no more and no less than the exact
>   final ELF bits of the output to contribute to selecting a unique ID.
>
> This is the best way to ensure that deterministic styles of ID generation
>   (i.e. cryptographic hash) will always yield identical results for repeated
>   builds reproduced precisely.

Comment: Kudos for the exemplar explanation. So this would be used mainly by distribution package builders. Currently I use -X options to add identifier strings to the go application.